# Where does Eclipse default to look for the JDK/JRE to use?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I have four or five difference java installations on my Linux computer.  I have set the JAVA_HOME in the bash_profile and bashrc to point to the latest version but whenever I install eclipse it finds a really old version that was installed and ignores the $JAVA_HOME.  Is there another system variable it's looking at to pick that one? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When launching, Eclipse looks for a JVM first in a `jre/` directory directly below the locaiton of the `eclipse` executable. If that isn't found, it will consult the `eclipse.ini` file. If there's no `-vm` argument in `eclipse.ini`, it will look on the system `$PATH` environment variable to find a java executable. As you probably know, the command "`which java`" will show you what java executable is found first on your `$PATH`.

This is all described in these pages:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher#Finding_a_VM.2C_Using_JNI_Invocation_or_Executing_Java

But you should take note that the *overwhelmingly recommended* way to get Eclipse to use a specific JVM is to specify it in `eclipse.ini` as described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Comment: Ah...it's checking the path BEFORE checking my $JAVA_HOME which makes perfect since because it's using the one that it's finding int he /usr/bin.

Answer (score 1):

To explicitly specify a JVM of your choice, you can use the -vm command line argument:

```
   eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\javaw.exe              ''start Java by executing the specified java executable
   eclipse -vm c:\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll         ''start Java by loading the jvm in the eclipse process
```

More information [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse?) .

As mentioned in Eclipse official FAQ : **Eclipse DOES NOT consult the JAVA_HOME environment variable.**

Comment: Yes but where is Eclipse looking that it's finding these old versions why isn't it checking the Java_Home variable in Bash_profile. Your answer is in Windows and my question was in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse.ini add :

-vm

%Path to java exec%

I don't remember if it should be the first argument, but add it first just to make sure. The file is located in your eclipse installation folder.

Comment: But it's defaulting to some location...where is this so I can remove or set the new Java there. I may be installing and reinstalling frequently I don't want the default to interfere.